# Managed Bean injection failure?

Tags: jsf, jdbc, managed-bean

I have a bean that is supposed to retrieve people from a database and then put them in a list which is displayed on the webpage. I keep getting a managed bean injection failure though and it seems to be caused by some sort of link between the database and server getting screwed up.

here is the stack trace. 
https://gist.github.com/blaxened/85a6861faf2373c26506

Here is the last part of the server log though it looks very similar to the stack trace.
https://gist.github.com/blaxened/f0bc6028d27cabcbd325

I know for a fact that the database/table is there [image: JDBC Database]

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.jsfprohtml5_AIM_war_1.0PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is the java class that connects to the database

```
package com.jsfprohtml5.firstapplication.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 *
 * @author Black
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYTABLE")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "AimStaff.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM AimStaff a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AimStaff.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM AimStaff a WHERE a.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AimStaff.findBySname", query = "SELECT a FROM AimStaff a WHERE a.sname = :sname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AimStaff.findByDatejoined", query = "SELECT a FROM AimStaff a WHERE a.datejoined = :datejoined"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AimStaff.findByLocale", query = "SELECT a FROM AimStaff a WHERE a.locale = :locale"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AimStaff.findByPhone", query = "SELECT a FROM AimStaff a WHERE a.phone = :phone")})
public class AimStaff implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "SNAME")
    private String sname;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "DATEJOINED")
    private String datejoined;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "LOCALE")
    private String locale;
    // @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;

    public AimStaff() {
    }

    public AimStaff(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSname() {
        return sname;
    }

    public void setSname(String sname) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }

    public String getDatejoined() {
        return datejoined;
    }

    public void setDatejoined(String datejoined) {
        this.datejoined = datejoined;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof AimStaff)) {
            return false;
        }
        AimStaff other = (AimStaff) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.jsfprohtml5.firstapplication.model.AimStaff[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

so I am unsure what is wrong. Let me know what other files need to be uploaded if any.

Comment: Can you upload the Layer of DB call, And the code in the flow?
Do you use some kind of ORM? Hibernate or EJB entity?

Comment: I am using an EJB Entity and yes I will post it shortly

Answer (score 0):

Your Table `MYTABLE` cannot be found by the Applicationserver. Can you verify that the server is able to connect and find the Table inside the configured datasource?

Can you post your `persistence.xml`?

Comment: I posted my persistence.xml but I am unsure how to go about verifying that my server (glassfish btw) can connect and find the table aside from running this program.

Comment: You could look inside the derby.log or post the server startup log.